# Environment variables - htaccess and php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, environment-variables

I need a little help with environment variables. After I setup the variable in .htaccess file like this:

```
SetEnv STATUSV "online"
```

How can I change the variable value permanently (global scope) using PHP. If I change the variable value like this:

```
apache_setenv("STATUSV", "offline");
```

or

```
putenv('STATUSV=offline');
```

Variable is only changed and exists in the session where I changed it.

What I want to do with this is to forbid clients to access files via direct url if the environment variable is set to specific value.

I appreciate every help and thank you in advance.

Comment: Store it into a database or a file.